# Docker nginx + php performance

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, fastcgi

I am using docker-compose to run an nginx container and a PHP container. I have a performance issue, where each 4th or 5th request to a simple PHP script takes several seconds (normally <<1s).

I have used `cgi-fcgi` to manually execute PHP requests, and can't reproduce the issue (the commands always complete quickly), so I suspect the issue is something to do with how nginx manages FCGI connections. Any ideas?

EDIT: It seems like it was a browser issue

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be resolved although no details have been provided